# Понимание неблокирующего send

Tags: c++, linux, c, сокет

В образовательных целях пишу http сервер без использования сторонних библиотек. В моей реализации все сокеты являются неблокирующими, и возникает вопрос, как реализовать отправку данных через `send`. Собственно сам вопрос заключается в поведении `send` при вызове на неблокирующем сокете.

###### Возвращаемое значение

Как сказано в `MAN send(2)`

> On success, these calls return the number of bytes sent.  On error, -1 is returned, and ***errno*** is set to indicate the error.

Не понимаю, что имеется ввиду, данные которые были реально отправлены, или данные, которые были помещены во внутренний буфер?

###### Данные не помещаются

В случае блокирующих сокетов всё понятно - в зависимости от возвращенного значения, вызываем `send` несколько раз, пока не будет передан весь буфер.
`MAN send(2)`

> When the message does not fit into the send buffer of the socket,
> ***send()*** normally blocks, unless the socket has been placed in
> nonblocking I/O mode.  In nonblocking mode it would fail with the
> error ***EAGAIN*** or ***EWOULDBLOCK*** in this case.  The ***select(2)*** call may
> be used to determine when it is possible to send more data.

Как я понимаю, `EAGAIN` и `EWOULDBLOCK` имеют идентичный смысл и означают, что данные переданы во внутренний буфер не полностью и нужно с помощью `select` дождаться когда сокет будет `writeable` и отправить оставшиеся данные. Но тут возникает вопрос, как понять сколько байт было передано, если `send` вернет -1?

Comment: Если вернет -1, то ни сколько не было передано. И не используйте `select`, используйте epoll.

Comment: @user7860670 Спасибо за совет, `epoll` изучу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Не понимаю, что имеется ввиду, данные которые были реально отправлены, или данные, которые были помещены во внутренний буфер?

`send` возвращает число байтов, которые ядро записало в буфер очереди отправки. Даже блокирующий `send` не будет дожидаться от сетевой карты подтверждения отправки данных.

> Но тут возникает вопрос, как понять сколько байт было передано, если send вернет -1?

Если есть свободное место в буферах, неблокирующий `send` запихнёт в них столько, сколько сможет, и вернёт число запихнутых байтов. `send` вернёт отрицательное число только в том случае, если окно на отправку заполнено целиком. В этом случае ваши данные останутся только вашими, ни один байт не будет скопирован в память ядра.